# How to order packages LESS + Remote-FTP?

Tags: ftp, ide, less, atom-editor

I just started using Atom editor and I installed two crucial packages for me: LESS and Remote-FTP.

They both run on file save, but unfortunately Remote-FTP sends my LESS file to FTP before LESS compiles it to CSS, so I have to upload the compiled CSS manually.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.ftpconfig` file for `remote-ftp` there is a configuration option, `watch`. When set, `remote-ftp` will watch for files edited outside of Atom editor and upload them.

Example configuration using `watch`:

```
{
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "host": "example.com",
    "port": 21,
    "user": "user",
    "pass": "pass",
    "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "secureOptions": null,
    "connTimeout": 10000,
    "pasvTimeout": 10000,
    "keepalive": 10000,
    "watch": ["./dist/stylesheets/main.css"] // Array of files to watch
}
```